# How to use NSLengthFormatter with NSTextField?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsformatter

I am trying to figure out how to use NSLengthFormatter with NSTextField. The output should be with local unit but no unit is displayed. I tried to set formatter manually in code and setStringValue:@"22" but it has the same result.
What am I doing wrongly?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A formatter creates a textual representation of an object and the methods of `NSLengthFormatter` take a double. Try `setObjectValue:@22.0`.

Comment: It must be 10.11.6 which is broken. It crashes when I try to setObjectValue or doubleValue (fresh install). I am trying to use KVC so using this will be a lot of code to write. I will test under 10.12 and probably ask again cause this  I have already tried. I though that it works out of the box like with other formatters.

Comment: I think `NSLengthFormatter` is a display only formatter, it doesn't work with editable text fields like `NSNumberFormatter`.